# How to map a blog to path

Tags: wordpress, blog, subdirectory

I would like to create a blog, and I want to have it in a custom URL. Moreover, I would like to host this blog in a subdirectory of my domain, i.e. `www.myurl.com/blog`, instead of a subdomain (e.g. `blog.myurl.com`).

My searches have shown that this is possible in both WordPress and Blogger, yet when I try to enter the custom URL, it tells me that the URL cannot end in a path. I then get told something about FTP publishing no longer being around, etc.

After chatting to some people in *Freenode #wordpress*, they mentioned that a self hosting WordPress blog allows you to do this.

Could someone please assist in explaining why a custom URL cannot end in a path for a blog in order to achieve this, and if I have understood something incorrectly, could one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this question about the hosted wordpress **.com** service or what? Because you suddenly bring up self-hosting but then immediately drop it to ask again about it being impossible to host in a sub-directory.

Comment: Are you asking to achieve this with Wordpress or are you hosting this yourself? If hosting yourself, then you can do what you want to do, just create the folder called blog and fill it with content.

Comment: I would rather do it with WordPress.com or Blogger. However, if self-hosting is the way forward for this, then I need to find out more on that side (I mentioned self hosting because one or two forums discussed this for WordPress.org and spoke about self-hosting).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot

> host this blog in a subdirectory of my domain, i.e.
>   www.myurl.com/blog, instead of a subdomain (e.g. blog.myurl.com).

in Blogger.    You may have found some old help materials saying that this was possible back in the FTP publishing days, but this option was removed some time ago.

With Blogger, your only option is to host the contents in Blogger itself, and publish your blog to a subdomain (e.g. blog.myurl.com).

Comment: I assume you are able to do this only with WordPress.org? And do you maybe know why they stopped that?

Comment: I cannot comment on Wordpress, or any of the other blogging tools.

Comment: I believe that Blogger stopped offering FTP publishing because hardly anyone was using it, so it wasn't worth the resources needed to maintain the separate FTP-version of the Blogger software.